# Which algorithms(paper) should be reproduced by a student to enter the field of computational fluid-structure interaction?

Tags: algorithms, multiphysics, fsi

We'd better not to reinvent the wheel. But without some programming, one can hardly understand  computational fluid-structure interaction. And I would like to know which papers or algorithms should a student reproduce in order to understand the big picture of computational fluid-structure interaction. It is better if there is a step-by-step order.

Answer (score 1):

Computational fluid-structure interaction is challenging endeavour. **The type of coupling algorithm you need to employ depends on the type of the problem you want to solve**. It is important to understand the difficulties associated with simulating different kinds of FSI problems.
You may refer to my recent presentation on the topic for the details. Title: [Computational fluid-structure interaction - Large deformations, added-mass & staggered schemes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344726671_Computational_fluid-structure_interaction_-_Large_deformations_added-mass_staggered_schemes)

For solving fluid rigid-body interaction problems using an explicit coupling, you can refer to my recent paper titled [A second-order accurate non-intrusive staggered scheme for the interaction of ultra-lightweight rigid bodies with fluid flow](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0029801820308945)

This is the pseudocode of our staggered scheme for FSI.
[image]

Some key features of the scheme are:

- Needs only the forces from the fluid solver, and displacement and velocity from the solid solver. Therefore, easy to couple different fluid and solid solvers as black boxes.
- Second-order accurate in time.
- Fluid and solid sub-problems are solved only once at every time step. Significant gains in computational efficiency.
- Demonstrated to cope with significant added-mass.

We have also successfully applied this scheme to some challenging fluid-flexible body interaction problems. See the presentation for the numerical examples. I am happy to discuss further if necessary.

For other similar schemes, you can refer to the references in my paper.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer and open source materials are inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time searching for the answer. Now I find two webpages very useful.

One is by the inventor of immersed boundary method, Prof. Peskin's course on IB:[LECTURES ON THE IMMERSED BOUNDARY METHOD](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Epeskin/ib_lecture_notes/index.html)

Another one is by a famous scholar on FSI(moving mesh, deforming mesh), Prof. Tezduyar's course: [COMPUTATIONAL FLUID MECHANICS](https://www.tafsm.org/MECH454/)

Prof. Peskin and Prof. Tezduyar's handwritten notes reflect their concise understanding and creative mind on the subject, which are of great inspirations to me.

Surely, my answer is partial. There are definitely other resources valuable.